# What is the class & method for refactoring of method parameters in Eclipse JDT API?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, refactoring, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I am attempting to refactor method parameters (adding/deleting/reordering) using Eclipse JDT API in Java projects. However, I am unable to find the API for the same in Eclipse JDT. Can someone provide the steps to do that using Eclipse JDT? Kindly note that I am not asking how to do it on the Eclipse IDE, but on doing it programmatically using Eclipse API.

Comment: If you know how to do it manually, you can use the _Plug-in Menu Spy_ (Alt+Shift+F2) to find the code and see how to do it programmatically.

Comment: Looks like `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.structure.ChangeSignatureProcessor` does most of the work - but this is an **internal** class so you can't use it in your code. You can read the source to see what needs to be done.